# How much OOP_Crazy should real life programmer be?

Tags: c#, oop, solid-principles, flexibility

**Given :**
Complex algorithm.

```
switch obj.field1 + "-" + obj.field2
case "A-A":
    return Sample(obj){Error = "Type can't be matched"}
case "A-B":
    {
    if(obj.field3 != null){
        var match = otherObjectCollection.FirstOrDefault(otherOb.field2 == obj.field3);
        return mathc != null? Sample(obj,match) : Sample(obj){Error="Can't find match"}
    }else{use field4...}
}
case "A-C":
{
var related = objectCollection.FirstOrDefault(parent.field4 == obj.field3);
if(related == null)
 return Sample(obj){Error = "Can't find parent"}
else {
  if(related.field3 != null){
       var match = otherObjectCollection.FirstOrDefault(otherOb.field2 == related.field3);
       return mathc != null? Samble(obj,match) : Sample(obj){Error="Can't find match"}
  }else{ use field 4 ...}

}
    }
```

And so on. A lot of tricky rules. I came up with next **decision:**

```
abstract class AggregationChain{
    protected MyObj Obj;
    abstract string Type{get;}
    abstract Priority Priority{get;}
    abstract bool Decide(MyObj obj);
    abstract Sample Aggregate(ICollection<MyObj> objects,ICollection<OtherObj> otherobjects);
    bool CanDecide(MyObj obj){
        if(Decide(obj)){
           Obj = obj;
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
 }
```

So now I can have ChainLinks for example:

```
 class ABAggregationChainLink{

        string Type{get{return "A-B"}}
        Priority Priority{get{return Priority.High}}
        bool Decide(MyObj obj){ 
           return obj.fiel2 != null;
        }
        Sample Aggregate(ICollection<MyObj> objects,ICollection<OtherObj> otherobjects){
            var match = OtherObjectCollection.FirstOrDefault(otherOb.field2 == obj.field3);
            return mathc != null? Samble(obj,match) : Sample(obj){Error="Can't find match"}
        }

     }
```

In this example i'll need to create one more A-B ChainLink that will handle "else" situation. And for all switch cases i'll need to create different ChainLinks. This of course increase number of classes and time for implementation but classes more suitable for unit testing and from my point of view more extandable and flexible.

**Question :**

1. I'm thinking - may be I'm overexcited by Open-Close and "Good
   programming" and for real life application it is better just create
   method with switch and take care of reusable parts?
2. I have
   filling that here may be better solution?

PS. This is not working C# code, I just tried to explain the main logic.

Comment: I have the strong feeling that it is waaaay too complicated. A simple switch would likely be more maintainable and readable.

Comment: You need to learn to draw the line between academic and practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When analysing something like this you can't just look at what it is now.

- Is that algorithm easily maintainable going forward?
- How easy is it
  to add new rules without changing existing functionality?
- How easy
  is it to test?
- Do you need to add new rules at runtime (plugin architectures)?

At 3 cases with some if elses, it probably doesn't really matter either way. At 40 cases with sub cases and a new requirement that it all needs unit testing? I'd prefer the clean isolation of a class per rule (or more likely a generic class with lambda expressions add to a collection of rules)

Your link class looks OK, but you'll still need the chain class to hold all the links together and work out which link to process. That could end up with a an structure to replace that switch statement like:

```
Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, List<Link>>> index;

if (index.ContainsKey(obj.Field1))
{
   var subIndex = index[obj.Field1];
   if (subIndex.ContainsKey(obj.Field2))
   {
      var linkList = subIndex[obj.Field2];
      foreach(var Link in linkList)
      {
          if (Link.Decide(obj))
          {
              return Link.Aggregate(objects, otherObjects);
          } 
      }
   }
}
```

If you change Decides signature to `Func<bool, MyObj>` and Aggregate `Func<Sample, ICollection<MyObj>,ICollection<OtherObj>>`

then you can add rules like

```
RuleChain.AddRule("A", "A", (o) => true, (objs, others) => Sample(obj){Error = "Type can't be matched"})
RuleChain.AddRule("A", "B",...
```

Comment: I think you're right, but I can't imagine how this rules should look like? Coz they doesn't have similar structure.

Comment: @ValentynVynogradskiy, difficult to say without knowing all the rules, you'd need to go through each one and work out what's the least information to put on your interface to be able to use them all. I've edited my answer to include some more detail on the Chain